# In SVG, is <path /> identical to <path></path>?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've been doing some work with SVG, and have been both writing it from scratch and generating it with javascript (including d3js).

One thing I have just noticed is that when I create a new element in javascript, ie by using

```
    var pathNode = document.createElementNS(svgns,"path");
    var pathElement = svg.appendChild(pathNode);
```

The resulting HTML is `<path></path>`. I've checked lots of D3 demos and this is how D3 produces the HTML too.

In all the docs I've read about SVG, I've never seen any mention of writing an SVG element this way. Do browsers treat the two identically? In all the browsers I've tested, the SVG displays correctly, and the W3C validator validates both versions so it would appear to be the case, but can anyone just clarify this to give me peace of mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is an XML language and in XML `<x></x>` is exactly the same as `<x/>`. [Per the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags)

*Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword EMPTY*